# Authorization bearer soap request

Tags: web-services, soap

I need to somehow include in my soap service envelope a header whose values are `"Authorization"` and `"Bearer xXsomeCode123xX"`, this is the part of the code I need to edit with the new header, which then returns me an xml document with some data requested through the soap web service.

```
            //SERVICE
            Service service = new Service();
            Call call = (Call) service.createCall();    
            call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new java.net.URL(endPointURL));
            call.setSOAPActionURI(soapActionURI);   

            //INVOKE
            SOAPEnvelope response = (SOAPEnvelope) call.invoke(new Message(soap.asXML()));              
            Document doc = new DOMReader().read(response.getAsDocument());  
            return doc;
```

This is what i see in SoapUI (and works with the header set like that)

[image: This is what i see in SoapUI]

I know the question is confusing, and I am, I've researched on the internet but almost every header is made of username:password fields, while i only have this "Authorization" to work on

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `WebServiceTemplate` you can do the method `marshalSendAndReceive` with a `WebServiceMessageCallback` , in these callback you can add `RequestHeader` in that you can put the Authorization and bearer + token, your method doWithMessage must looks like as bellow:

```
public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage webServiceMessage) throws IOException, TransformerException {
                    TransportContext context = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();
                    HeadersAwareSenderWebServiceConnection connection = (HeadersAwareSenderWebServiceConnection) context.getConnection();
                    connection.addRequestHeader("Authorization", String.format("Bearer %s", "********"));

                }
```

More info in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48623512/cannot-add-http-headers-to-message-with-springs-webservicetemplate)

Answer (score 0):

To add bearer authorization header in SoapUI you have to:
(keep in mind that Bearer token belongs to OAuth2)

- click on "Auth" button in the left bottom corner of the request's window
- using "Authorization" dropdown, select Add new Authorization.
- then - Type -> OAuth2, press OK. you'll see a input field named
  Access Token. Just insert you token in it.

Running your request, on http log you'll see something like that:
:DEBUG:>> "Authorization: Bearer .... [\r][\n]"

Comment: In SoapUI, I execute the authenticate request, which gives me a bearer token.  Great.  Now I copy & paste (carefully, to get the entire thing), into the Auth / OAUTH2 portion of my data request, and click the Play button.  But it doesn't hit my code breakpoint, nor does it show any results.  Instead, I get error 401, Bearer error="invalid_token".  I for sure used the right token.  Any ideas or screen shots to help out?

Comment: I should add that I also obtained a bearer token via CURL, and submitted my data request, and I get an empty response via CURL.  Again, no breakpoint hit in the code.  What are the possible issues?

Comment: If I take off the Authorize requirement on the endpoint, then it executes, hits the breakpoint, and returns data.